# Laravel 302 redirect issue

Tags: laravel, routes

I am trying to get info from action, but when click, just page refresh and in console I get code 302 and stay on current page.

I read a lot of similar topics here but found nothing.

I am trying to execute http://laravel2.lo/getUserChannels?user_id=2

Laravel 5.7.16

route:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::view('createUser', 'createuser');
    Route::view('createChannel', 'createchannel');
    Route::view('joinChannel', 'joinchannel');


    Route::get('profile', 'UserController@profile');
    Route::get('users', 'UserController@users');
    Route::get('getChannelUsers', 'UserController@getChannelUsers');
    Route::get('getUserChannels', 'ChannelController@getUserChannels');

});
```

ChannelController:

```
class ChannelController extends Controller
{
    public function getUserChannels(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'user_id' => 'required|integer',
        ]);

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = User::find($request->user_id);

        return view('singleuser', ['channels' => $user->channels, 'username' => $user->name]);
    }
}
```

In the log file no errors.

Thanks for any help and advise.

Comment: Redirect to the same page means a validation exception without a configured error route. To check if this is the case try wrapping the `validate` in a `try { /* validate code */ } catch (ValidationException $e) { dd($e); }` and see if that says anything

Comment: ValidationException {#274 ▼
  +validator: Validator {#273 ▶}
  +response: null
  +status: 422
  +errorBag: "default"
  +redirectTo: null
  #message: "The given data was invalid."
  #code: 0
  #file: "/home/suspiria/www/laravel2.lo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php"
  #line: 315
  trace: {▶}
}

Comment: it happens when i am trying to exec http://laravel2.lo/getUserChannels?user_id=2

Comment: public function getUserChannels(Request $request)
    {
        try { /* validate code */
            $this->validate($request, [
                'user_id' => 'required|integer',
            ]);
        }
        catch (ValidationException $e) {
            dd($e);
        }


        /** @var User $user */
        $user = User::find($request->user_id);

        return view('singleuser', ['channels' => $user->channels, 'username' => $user->name]);
    }

Comment: Since you are using 5.7 it's recommended you do `$request->validate([...rules])` I think `$this->validate($request->all().///` should work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll receive query params as anything other than strings, so your integer validation fails.

To improve your error handling you could customize your `App\Exceptions\Handler`, catch your `ValidationException` errors with something like `get_class()` or `instanceOf` and do some neat stuff there

And of course you could not use query params at all by using `Route::get('getUserChannels/{id}', 'controller@show');` and access it /getUserChannels/2 - then you could probably validate it as an integer

---

You could go with

`Route::get('getUserChannels/{id}', ...`

```
public function getUserChannels($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    return view('singleuser', [
        'channels' => $user->channels,
        'username' => $user->name
    ]);
}
```

Then it would just throw a 404 if string, not found etc...

Comment: try { /* validate code */
            $this->validate($request, [
                'user_id' => 'required|string',
            ]);
        }
        catch (ValidationException $e) {
            dd($e);
        }  

also have a fail. with string too

Comment: perhaps dump your `$request->all()` and see what you get before validation

Comment: dd($request->all()); 

shows 

// 20181209141939
// http://laravel2.lo/getUserChannels/2

[
  
]

very strange

Comment: it's about I've made routes Route::get('getUserChannels/{id}', 'ChannelController@getUserChannels');

Comment: if you have a route that's `getUserChannels/{id}` then you can access that id just by having `public function show($id) {` or `public function show(Request $request, $id) {`


Then instead of validating if it's an integer, you could accept whatever and do a `User::findOrFail($id)` and let your app throw a 404 if it's a string, unknown ID integer or whatever

Answer (score 0):

```
class ChannelController extends Controller
    {
        public function getUserChannels(Request $request)
        {
            $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), ['user_id' => 'required|integer']);

             if($validator->fails())
             {
               $error = $validator->errors()->first();

                 dd($error);
            }

            /** @var User $user */
            $user = User::find($request->user_id);

            return view('singleuser', ['channels' => $user->channels, 'username' => $user->name]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes. this works. but anyway I am getting empty $request->all().

Comment: If you use this http://laravel2.lo/getUserChannels?user_id=2 url, then $request->all()  should't empty. I checked it in my machine.